# Can't Write to Public Files but Permissions Appear Fine

Tags: files

Need the internet to confirm my sanity. On a Drupal 7 site it's saying "The directory sites/default/files is not writable." So I checked every permission but I don't see the issue. Since this isn't a public server, I temporarily turned off SELinux. Another Drupal 8 site is running on the same server with the exact same permissions. What am I missing?

`getenforce` output:

```
Permissive
```

`ps aux | grep httpd` output:

```
root     29064  0.0  0.1 262224  6492 ?        Ss   18:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   29065  0.0  0.0 261884  3672 ?        S    18:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   29066  0.0  0.2 1188648 10040 ?       Sl   18:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   29067  0.0  0.2 1778408 8000 ?        Sl   18:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

`/sites/default/files` is a symlink and the permission should be ignored

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    31 Mar 18 18:14 files -> /mnt/efs/website/publicfiles/
```

So let's go down the tree

```
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 6144 Feb 17 23:27 efs
```

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 6144 Feb 17 23:28 website
```

```
drwxrwxr-x 110 apache web 141312 Mar 18 18:16 publicfiles
```

EDIT (from comment below):
`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
... server info ...
<Directory "/var/www/html/website/public_html">
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: Can you verify what webserver you are using?  And if you are using Apache, whether 'Options +FollowSymLinks' is set in the conf?

Comment: @mpdonadio Good question. Looks like that's set as well. It was set to Options FollowSymLinks for /var/www/html. My virtualhost also has AllowOverride All and the .htaccess has the same line. Just to test I added it to the virtualhost directory context and restarted. Nothing.

Comment: What about the permissions of the parent folder? E.g. does `$ [sudo] chmod u+w /sites/default/` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve this. The entire purpose of this cloned server was to test out speed improvements from PHP-FPM. So since PHP evaluation is essentially offloaded to PHP-FPM, it doesn't matter if `httpd` has permissions, it matters whether the `php-fpm` process has permissions.

`ps aux | grep php-fpm` output:

```
root      5744  0.0  0.3 462268 14988 ?        Ss   16:45   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
php-fpm   5745  0.0  0.9 467332 35196 ?        S    16:45   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm   5746  0.0  0.4 466656 16528 ?        S    16:45   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm   5747  0.0  0.3 466656 14032 ?        S    16:45   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
php-fpm   5748  0.0  0.3 466656 14028 ?        S    16:45   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

`groups php-fpm`:

```
php-fpm : php-fpm
```

So the ownership of my folder as `apache:web` is what doesn't fit. I just added the user `php-fpm` to the group `web` and changed things back to 775.

```
sudo usermod -aG web php-fpm
```

I would love comments on pros and cons of what I see as other possible solutions, especially from a security perspective:

1) Add `php-fpm` to the 'web' group.

2) Make `php-fpm` the owner, and httpd as member of `web` so it can still serve the files later.